# Removing the "Javascript" from alert()

Tags: javascript, alert

Whenever I use the javascript `alert()` function, there is always some form of text above the message. I believe it is different for every browser.

- Chrome displays "Javascript Alert"
- Safari displays "Javascript" (shown below)
- iOS Safari displays the website URL.

Is there any way to suppress this? I just want my `alert()` to say: "Alert Text". To be honest, I don't even know where to start (I have little/no Javascript experience) so I haven't tried anything yet. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

```
alert("Alert Text");
```

[image]

Comment: You can try reverse engineering each JavaScript/browser engine (at least those which aren't already opensource), then use dynamic library interposition (`LD_PRELOAD` on Linux, `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` on OS X/iOS, etc.) for altering the behaviour of the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's there as a security measure so that the end user knows the browser itself isn't sending the message, but rather the developer of some script.

...that said, there's nothing stopping you from creating a custom alert that looks very similar to the browser alert.

Comment: Made a basic example of a custom made alert [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/U4GHk/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The is an implementation detail. You cannot change this.